# How to get INDEX formula to return you certain vaule, when different conditions in different columns has to be satisfied?

Tags: excel, date, indexing

My goal is for Excel to return me the "Price" of a certain "Item" (let's say Banana), within a certain "Date" range (let's say within March 2020). Also, it has to be the latest date in this range. So, in this case, I want Excel to return me the price "30" (the price of Banana), as 15.3.2020 is later than 1.3.2020. Imagine I have a lot of data, with a lot of items, dates, and prices.

The formula I have tried in the picture below is in the cell C10 and it is not working.

'=(INDEX(H7:J21;LARGE(AND(I7:I21="Banana";H7:H21>=DATE(2020;3;1);H7:H21<=DATE(2020;3;31));1);3))'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items are not repeated on the same date you can combine `SUMPRODUCT` and `AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A16=AGGREGATE(14;6;(B2:B16=G2)*(E2<=A2:A16)*(F2>=A2:A16)*A2:A16;1))*(G2=B2:B16)*C2:C16)
```

[image]

Comment: 2 sub-questions: 1. How come earlier date works with <= instead of >= (and vice versa for later date)? 2. Where can I learn more (logic behind) about SUMPRODUCT doing "magic" or things it's not meant to do in the first place?

Comment: 1. It depends on which side the reference date is - I wrote ```(E2 <= A2: A16)``` and ```(F2> = A2: A16)```, which means that March 1 must be less than dates in ```A2: A16``` and March 31 must be greater than dates in ```A2: A16```. You can type upside down ```(A2: A16> = E2)``` and ```(A2: A16 <= F2)```, which means that ```A2: A16``` must be greater than March 1 and less than March 31. In both cases, the function will return ```TRUE``` if the date will be in March.

Comment: 2. The logic of ```SUMPRODUCT``` is simple - this function multiplies ranges or arrays together and returns the sum of products The key is hidden in boolean logic. The excel converts each ```TRUE``` to 1 and each ```FALSE``` to 0. In this case, multiplying multiple criteria creates a single array whose elements are summed up:

Comment: 1. With ```AGGREGATE``` function we find the largest date that meets the criteria of 15.03.20 and compares it to the whole array, resulting in {0,0, ..., 0,1}                         2. then we search for which Item are bananas and get {0,1, ..., 1,1}                             3. then we return all prices {55.52, ..., 54.30}   4. multiplying it  ```SUMPRODUCT``` gives one parameter - 30 (i.e. ```SUMPRODUCT (30)```)  The best I can recommend, see examples of solutions with ```SUMPRODUCT``` right here in SO. I haven't found anything better.